# Deploy react application with heroku problem

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku

Hello guys I created a MERN app, and it works fine, but I couldn't deploy it.

I keep getting this build log error :

```
./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css TypeError: stagedAutoprefixer is not a function
```

I checked my package.json and

```
"overrides": {
    "autoprefixer": "10.4.5"
  }
```

already exists if anyone know how to solve this let me know .
I appreciate any help!

Comment: This is not enough to determine what went wrong

Comment: what do I need to add

Comment: is there a part of your code you're importin `autoprefixer`